# How can I center something with css consistently between browsers?

Tags: html, css

I'm working on http://jonreeve.com/behaviour/ and trying to get the menu on the front page centered. It consists of a ul tag with li elements in it, surrounded by a div for the whole menu. The other elements seem to center fine, but for some reason I can't get this menu to center properly.

I hear to center things with CSS, you have to set the width to a certain value, and then set margin-right: auto; margin-left: auto;. The problem is, whatever values I set for width manage to center it, but only in one of two browsers. Setting the correct value for one puts the other one out of center.

I thought this could be a problem with the way the font is being displayed, and I tried lots of different ways of changing the font size, but it still doesn't quite add up. I also played around with setting the width on the ul instead of in the div, or setting values to width: auto; or width: 100%; yet nothing seems to fix this problem.

Here are values that I found center the menu: 
    /* works with chromium width: 43em;  */
    /* works with firefox  width: 50em; */
    /* works with firefox  width: 800px; */
    /* works with chromium width: 700px */

EDIT: fixed URL

Comment: Getting a 404 on your example page, could you fix that or create an example at jsfiddle.net? Otherwise, setting a fixed width on a block element and `margin: 0 auto;` should center the element, pretty much in every browser.

Comment: Please post the relevant code, as there are different ways to center different types of elements!

Comment: I think the url is http://jonreeve.com/behaviour/

Answer (score 1):

Best way is to use **display: inline-block** on the `ul` element and **display: inline** on the `li`. Then you can use **text-align center** on the container `div`.

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/c4urself/gF3GZ/

**css**

```
div.element {
    text-align: center;
}

div.element ul {
    display: inline-block;
}
div.element ul li {
    display: inline;
}
```

**html**

```
<div class="element">
    <ul>
        <li>Test 1</li>
        <li>Test 2</li>
        <li>Test 3</li>
        <li>Test 4</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Please don't just provide a link to jsFiddle, add the code to the answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not getting consistent centering, you problem is likely that your page has invlaid markup, invalid css, or that you aren't using a doctype or some other thing is forcing some browsers into quriksmode.

You don't say which browsers you're having problems with.  However, i think the real problem  you have is twofold.  First, your menu segments do not fill the menu container, so therefore it's not centering the segments.  The menu itself is centered.  Second, your use of negative margins on you link elements is making it off-center as well.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, the problem is some default margins/padding on the `ul`, combined with the large width on the `#menu` container, so that the `ul` is left-aligned within your centered `#menu`, and then shifted a little to the left due to its default padding.

Add this at the top of your CSS, as a good general purpose "reset" to make sure everything only has the margins/padding you want:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

And then change the relevant CSS to the following:

```
#menu {
    width: 50em;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}
    #menu ul {
        display: inline-block;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I like to use [this technique for centering floats](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menus/centered.html).

CSS:

```
#menu { 
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#menu ul {
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    left: 50%; 
    padding: 0;
}
#menu ul li { 
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    right: 50%;
    border-left: 1px solid white;
}
#menu ul li a { 
    margin-right: -4px;
    background-color: #6d7297; 
    margin-left: -4px;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    border-left: 1px solid white; 
    color: white; 
    font-family: 'Crimson Text', serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bolder;
    font-stretch: semi-expanded;
    font-size: larger;
     font-variant: small-caps;    
    /*text-shadow: black 1px 1px 0px;*/
}
#menu ul li a:hover { 
    background-color: white;
    color: #6d7297; 
} 

#menu ul li:hover { 
    background-color: white;
    color: gray; 
}
```

Preview: http://jsfiddle.net/Wexcode/vreLY/

Answer (score 0):

You're link has a typo in it.....

I found it anyway. The menu is centered. If you put a background color on #menu in the index.css file you'll see that the designated width of 50ems is indeed centered in the window. However, the list items of your menu do not fill 50ems. Setting the width of #menu to 710px does center it. if you would rather not use a fixed width, you can move the #menu div inside the #contentContainer div...

```
<div id="contentContainer">
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a id="aboutTextButton">About the Text</a></li>
        <li><a id="aboutProjectButton">About the Project</a></li>
        <li><a id="catalogButton" onclick="displayResult('catalog.xml','catalog.xsl')">Browse the Images</a></li>
        <li><a id="transcriptionButton" onclick="displayResult('behaviour.xml','xml-style2.xsl')">Read the Text</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>


</div>
```

and adjust the css....

```
#menu { 
padding: 0 40px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use **margin: 0 auto;** in you div

> ```
> <div id="menu" style="margin: 0 auto;">
> ```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried simply using css rule:

```
margin: auto;
```

Comment: Cool, I love when people down-vote without posting a reason. Very helpful.

Answer (score -1):

You can generally center div tags with CSS margin parameters.
With margin-left: auto; and margin-right: auto; it should work.

```
<body>
<div style="margin-right:auto; margin-left:auto;">
and here the other code.
</div>
</body>
```

Then the div-tag should be centered.